# Is there any way to include my custom libcrypto and libssl in my apk instead of the android one

Tags: android

I have a file named libsetup.so which is using a specific version of libcrypto.so and libssl.so. But when I am flashing my apk it is using the libcrypto and libssl of android. Is there any way I can write a rule in Android.mk file to include the specific libraries.

I tried changing the name of my libcrypto and libssl into something else and then include it but it is not working